# unable activate php-fpm /status|ping -page with nginx on debian6 + PLESK 12

Tags: nginx, debian, php, status, plesk

i am not able to get the php-fpm "/status|ping" -page to work.

a few specs:
OS Debian 6.0.10
Plesk version 12.0.18 Update #35, last updated at Feb 13, 2015 08:37 PM
PHP version is 5.4.37 (got it from dotdeb)

installed NGINX and PHP-FPM via upgrade feature thingy on PLESK 12

REMARK: example.com = my-real-hidden-domain-name.com

*** configs and files ***

*** section WEB SERVER SETTINGS
activated nginx settings
checkmark: Smart static files processing
NO checkmark: Serve static files directly by nginx
checkmark: Process PHP by nginx

*** Additional nginx directives

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
    allow all;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock;
    #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # REMARK: not touched
}
location = /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
}
```

*** section PHP SETTINGS ***

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

under directory /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf
added a custom php.ini file

*** php.ini contends: ***

```
[example.com]
; Don't override following options, they are relied upon by Plesk internally

; Following options can be overridden
 chdir = /

request_slowlog_timeout = 5s
slowlog = /var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/example.com/slowlog-example.com.log
; By default use on demand spawning (this requires php-fpm >= 5.3.9)
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
; Following pm.* options are used only when 'pm = dynamic'
pm.start_servers = 3
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 500
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
 env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
 env[TMP] = /tmp
 env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
 env[TEMP] = /tmp
catch_workers_output = yes
pm.status_path = /status
ping.path = /ping
ping.response = bong
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

*** php.ini contends end ***

*** configs and files end ***

so far the website is working fine with this setup, all php goes through nginx/php-fpm

*** now the problem to fix ***
if i try to view h**p://example.com/status

all i get is 
a blank page in browsers

*** $ tail -f /var/log/php5-fpm.log  -n 600 -s 10 ***

```
16-Feb-2015 21:31:52] WARNING: [pool example.com] child 21532 said into stderr: "NOTICE: Access to the script '/status' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"
```

*** /var/www/vhosts/example.com/logs/example.com/proxy_access_log ***

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [17/Feb/2015:16:59:11 +0100] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
```

*** script test-php-fpm.sh: ***

```
SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
QUERY_STRING= \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock
```

script end *****
 $ ./test-php-fpm.sh  **outputs via SSH: ***

```
Access to the script '/status' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)
Status: 403 Forbidden
Content-type: text/html

Access denied.
```

*** output end (blank line is there "output?" ***

```
$ curl http://example.com/status
```

just outputs NOTHING

*** ls -l /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock ***

```
srw-rw---- 1 root psaserv 0 Feb 15 19:58 /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock
```

according to several tutorials it should work, but does not.

i try searching for different solutions on the internet about 
PHP-FPM NGINX and "BLANK PAGES" OR "ACCESS DENIED" errors, but nothing help.

according to this guide 
(REMARK:  i DID NOT COPY THE FILES mentioned there, because i wanna just use plesk)
h**p://timreeves.de/internet-technologie/server-tuning-2-nginx-und-php-fpm-unter-ubuntu-12-04-lts-und-plesk-11-5/

i also did

```
$ usermod -aG psacln nginx
```

i do not want to go through TCP/IP, keep the socket file pls.
can someone please give me an advice.

mfg/wkr

Comment: I've got similar problem. Doing `curl http://127.0.0.1/status` shows blank result. No Error.

Answer (score 2):

As the error (by the php-fpm) states, the access is denied because php-fpm is limited to security.limit_extensions (in your case to .php and .html which is not what you want I think, you don't want to parse .html as .php I guess).

The pm.status_path is /status and it doesn't end with .php (or .html) extension, hence the error.

As I ran into this problem myself and found your question in google, I tell you that my solution was to set:

```
pm.status_path = /status.php
```

and use it in the nginx location too, and it works.

The other solution would be to allow php-fpm to run any file without extension limit (empty setting to security.limit_extensions) but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: as this question is an old thing, i solved it. al long time ago.

Comment: thanks for tryingi solved it. a looooong time ago.
i solved it, installing a debian server from scratch, ! without plesk !.
as a nice sideeffect i learned config things are much more easy if you know how things/configs are working. without any "config (not)solution". its now easier for me to edit the configfiles, than the pain running and analyse faults in some Web-UI(s)

Comment: @leluxefou What have you put into your nginx config?

Comment: @b4d. i never solved this with plesk. see above your question. i simply use the solution at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_stub_status_module.html.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your problem, but it may simplify it. Regex locations are position sensitive which can be problematic. Avoiding them in exchange for a little duplication will rule this out and allow your config to scale with fewer problems. There is also a performance advantage to using "=" locations.

```
location = /status {
    allow all;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location = /ping {
    allow all;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location = /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i tried that also before. 
i*ve now done it again, just to be sure.
and it gives the same output as mentioned before. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Replace `location` on `nginx.conf` with this:

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$
{
    allow all;

    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock;
}
```